What does it mean when vector quantity is negative?
I’ve seen in some problems that vector quantity is negative. For example, negative Coulomb means that two charges attract… negative acceleration means that object is slowing down. However, magnitude of a vector quantity cannot be negative mathematically. And vector quantity is defined by direction and magnitude. Idea physically makes sense to me, but what is a more rigorous mathematical explanation for such cases?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

I think the negative you are referring to is about opposite direction, not negative magnitude of vector

$-\vec v$ is a vector which has the same magnitude as $\vec v$ but points in the opposite direction. So $\vec v + (-\vec v)=0$.

As I said in my question, I’ve seen things like F = -200N. Without a vector symbol (and it’s not bolded), what is meant by just F? It’s usually magnitude that’s written in such way, but magnitude cannot be negative.

@AlexanderDjurovich it is a shorthand used when the force is along a specific axis, then the force will have components only along that axis, whose absolute value will be equal to the magnitude of the force. So a negative F means that the force is pointing in the negative direction of such  axis.

The sign of a vector is mostly a result of the coordinate system chosen, or another arbitrary definition.
For example, negative acceleration means an object is slowing down is only true if the velocity is positive.
For example, if:
$$ \vec a \equiv (a_x, a_y, a_z) = (-1, 0, 0) $$
then
$$ a_x < 0 $$
but it's slowing down (speeding up) if:
$$ \vec v = (\pm|v|, 0, 0) $$
Really, talking about components doesn't have any physical meaning.
Note the statement:
$$ a = \vec a \cdot \frac{\vec v}{||v||} < 0 $$
does mean it's slowing down, but here $a$ is scalar, which has coordinate independent meaning. $a_x$ is not a scalar, it's just a number.
In the case of an electric field, say from a point charge, you would think the field converging on the charge has different physical meaning than diverging from it, per:
$$ \vec \nabla E = \mp|q|/\epsilon_0 $$
However, the sign of $q$ depends on the definition of $e$, the electron charge..and that is arbitrary.
With either definition: opposite (like) charges attract (repel). In your question "negative Coulomb" doesn't really mean anything.
An exception may be with gradients...
$$ \vec \nabla \phi $$
points in the direction of increasing $\phi$.

So you are trying to say that saying Coulomb force of F = -200N actually means: vector F = -200N r where r represents unit vector? But magnitude is +200N?

magnitude is always positive (4-vectors not withstanding). A negative force $\vec f = -|f|\hat f$ points in the opposite direction of $\hat f$, but it doesn't mean anything fundamentally because in the coordinates with $\hat f' \equiv -\hat f$, you have $\vec f' = +|f'|\hat f' $, which is positive, but they are the same vector: $\vec f = \vec f'$.

Vectors don't have a "sign", per se. You can choose to represent a vector in terms of its components. For example, suppose we had some velocity vector $\vec{v}$. You can decompose $\vec{v}$ as
$$
\vec{v} = v_x \hat{i} + v_y \hat{j} + v_z \hat{k}
$$
where $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$ are unit vectors pointing in the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions. Then, the components of $\vec{v}$, namely $v_x$, $v_y$, and $v_z$, are just ordinary real numbers, and these numbers can be positive or negative. If the $x$ component $v_x$ is positive, then it means that if you travel along $\vec{v}$ from tail to tip, your $x$ coordinate will increase; while if $v_x$ is negative, it means if you move along $\vec{v}$, your $x$ coordinate will decrease.
One reason it doesn't make sense to say if a vector is "positive" or "negative", is that it has multiple components. You can have a vector where all three components are positive, but you can also have a vector where $v_x$ is positive but $v_y$ is negative and $v_z$ is zero. What "sign" would you assign in this situation? The concept of "sign" doesn't really help us think about properties of vectors, so we don't try to define a way to assign a sign to a vector.
You can multiply vectors by real numbers. It simply rescales their length, and possible reverses their direction. For example, $2\vec{v}$ is a vector that points in the same direction as $\vec{v}$ but is twice as long. $-1 \vec{v}$, usually written $-\vec{v}$, is a vector with the same magnitude as $\vec{v}$ but pointed in the opposite direction. However, there is no sense in which $\vec{v}$ is "positive" and $-\vec{v}$ is "negative", or vice versa, since vectors are not real numbers and don't have signs.
The magnitude of $\vec{v}$, sometimes denoted as $|\vec{v}|$, is always positive
$$
|\vec{v}| = \sqrt{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}} = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2} \geq 0
$$
This is true whether or not the components are positive or negative.

I really like your answer and I find it very logical. I’d like to add one bonus question: in formula for distance traveled in motion with constant acceleration, we are dealing with magnitudes only and not vectors. However, it’s usually said that acceleration vector points opposite to velocity and thus we have the minus sign. Why are vectors even mentioned here?

@AlexanderDjurovich Fundamentally, a problem like that does involve vectors. The velocity of a moving particle has both a magnitude and direction. The acceleration also has a magnitude (how much the speed is changing per unit time) and a direction (parallel to velocity == particle speeding up, antiparallel == particle slowing down). However, constant acceleration is a 1-d problem. So, let's say, the particle is moving in the $x$ direction. Then $\vec{v}=v_x \hat{i}$ and $\vec{a}=a_x \hat{i}$; both velocity and acceleration have only one component. So you can also solve the problem(...)

(...) only talking about these components, without directly talking about the vector. The information in that one component is equivalent to the information in the vector itself, and you can write, $v_x=\pm |\vec{v}|$. But, this is special to working in one dimension.

Yes it does make sense to me. However, distance was used in solutions, but not position which makes it quite confusing for me. Equations involving distance traveled are specifically scalar equations coming from formula $v = \dfrac{ds}{dt}$ . What I don’t understand is why are vectors even mentioned here? My guess is that because equation $\vec{r} = \vec{r_0} + \vec{v_0}t - 1/2 \vec{a}t^2$ has magnitude $\Delta{r} = v_0 t - 1/2 at^2$ and in this case $s = \Delta{r}$ considering that particle is moving only in one direction.

"Negative" vectors only make sense in one dimension. Such vectors don't have a direction only orientation. It makes sense to use + and - to denote orientation because two vectors of equal magnitute but opposite orientation sum to zero and more generally add as if they are positive and negative.

I'd beg to differ - once you have defined a coordinate basis, you can have negative vectors in any number of dimensions. It is simply the vector flipped in all coordinates, however many.

Sure, I wanted to keep it simple. They differ only by orientation.

Let $\vec v = v\,\hat v$ where $v$ is the component of $\vec v$ in the $\hat v$ direction.
Then you can interpret $\vec {v'} = -v\,\hat v$ in one of two ways:
$\vec {v'} = -v\,(\hat v)$ with $-v$ the component of $\vec {v'}$ in the $\hat v$ direction
$\vec {v'} = v\,(-\hat v)$ with $v$ the component of $\vec {v'}$ in the $(-\hat v) = \hat {v'}$ direction where $\hat v + \hat {v'} = \hat v (- \hat v)=\vec 0$
In the example that you give with $F = -200\,\rm N$ there is an implied direction, say $\hat z$ (upwards), and so the force $\vec F = -200\,\hat z$ has magnitude $200$ in the downward direction or has component $-200$ in the upward direction.
You might meet this when using Newton's second law $\vec F = m\,\vec a$ having defined vertically upwards as the positive.
Using the unit vector in the upward direction, $\hat z$, instead of writing $F\hat z= m\,\hat a\,\hat z$, the version $F=m\,a$ is used with $F$ and $a$ as the components of force and acceleration in the $\hat z$ direction.
